# How to disable bracket balancing in Xcode9

Tags: xcode

When I hit delete-key to remove the single ']' character like this in Xcode 9.0 (9A235),

```
id object = [] ;
              ^
              |
              caret position
```

Xcode deletes TWO characters automatically.

```
id object =  ;
            ^
            |
            caret position
```

I know this behavior is implemented for convenience. BUT I don't like this. I can't find options in preferences window. please teach me how to disable this behavior.

Comment: A similar annoyance applies to `" "`. Seriously, constantly changing the way this kind of stuff behaves os the **_worse_** Apple can do UX-wise.

Comment: Have you tried playing with the various checkboxes in Xcode > Preferences > Text Editing > Editing Tab > Code Completion?

Comment: Yes, i tried it. I think those options does not take effects to disable this behavior.

Comment: If we are lucky there is some setting in a plist somewhere that can be overriden from the command line or something. I'm not aware of any.

Comment: No option, and it is still in the release of Xcode 10.0

Comment: Still does not appear to be any option as of XCode 11.  Disabling all code completion settings still does not disable this annoying behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if my swift file happens to contain commented out code, specifically of the following form, the auto balancing of the respective bracket type will stop working.

```
// { bla
// }

// [ bla
// ]

// ( bla
// )
```

So you can try this by copy pasting the above comments into a swift source file and see that auto-balancing will stop working.

The bug will be triggered for both block comments and line comments, but the open and close brackets must be on separate lines, and the open bracket must be followed by something (eg "bla" as in the examples).